# Как получить страницу через ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

На моем сайте нужно вывести страницу другого сайта, то бишь, мне нужно получить страницу из другого домена. Например: мой сайт www.mysite.com и мне нужно в него поместить текст из сайта www.example.com(который находится в каком либо диве)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

код на вашем сайте:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="site"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var check = $('#site');
$.ajax({    type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.example.com/example.php?xx=value",
            cache: true,
            async: true,
            success:function(response)
                {check.html(response);}
            });
```

и на той странице куда идет запрос (www.example.com/example.php) должен быть код разрешающий запросы ajax и иметь структуру html:

**PHP:**

```
header('Content-type: text/html');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: а если нет на странице Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *, то возможно как то получить контент из этой страницы?

Comment: Через запросы уже нет. А вообще, то есть стандарт безопасности кросс-доменного обмена данными - CORS, который поддерживают браузеры и требует наличия Access-Control-Allow-Origin с правильными настройками. При Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* сайт легко уязвим для хакерских атак